# What is the regex for any set of characters other than "*/"

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I have been working with Lex, and encountered a problem of finding *comments* in a C program and removing them in the final output. To accomplish this I need to identify any occurrence of `*/` (this is how a traditional multiline comment ends!).

Then my problem is reduced to a subproblem of accepting any sequence of characters other than `*/` . I tried out a several ways for accomplishing this. I tried out: `[^*\/]`, and reasonably it did not work. Any help or suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: `[^*\/]` is a non `*` or `/`. Does lex use PCRE, if so I think `\*\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.` would work.. (also if `/` is not a delimiter it doesn't need to be escaped)

Comment: @Bishwajit Purkaystha Checkout the Regex101.com links. That site as an explanation of the Regex on the right that will do a far better job explaining the regex then I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of lookahead and lookbehind to achieve the top-level solution.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8Zpmhu/2)

```
/(?<=\/\*).*(?=\*\/)/s
```

This will insure everything (assuming newlines and the `s` modifier) between `/*` and `*/` is captured in a group.

For "What is the regex for any set of characters other than “*/”"

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xiCIvi/1)

That is as simple as:

```
/[^\/\*]/
```

Comment: You seem to have swapped the lookahead and the lookbehind. BTW, they're zero-length matches so not need in the capture group - the entire match will give you what is required: https://regex101.com/r/8Zpmhu/2

Comment: @Dmitry Egorov You are correct. This is my morning warmup "coffee" question. Thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hey, @MattSizzle your solution worked. But can you please elaborate on how you did actually build it? I'm really a novice. Thanks.

Comment: `[^\/\*]` is not `any set of characters other than “*/”"` it is any character other than `*` **or** `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match any character sequence followed by `*/` two-character sequence literally. A positive look-ahead will you to achieve this. For possible multiple `*/` occurrences you need a positive look-behind or start of the text (`(?<=^|\*\/)`):

```
(?<=^|\*\/).*?(?=\*\/)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/y88e0T/2

Comment: But, this doesn't work on this case. For the case: `is this */ how you do */` I want to find the two segments: [is this] and [how you do].  But your solution gives [is this */ how you do]. Moreover the comments may span multiline.

Comment: Yes, I saw it Could you direct me where I can learn Regular Expressions effectively?  Thanks for answering.

Comment: @BishwajitPurkaystha, the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean is good as an intro. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great resource but not quite easy to absorb due to huge amount of the information. Yet I utterly advise you to consider it. The [SO info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) has quite a number of useful links on the topic. And as MattSizzle already said, check out the Regex101.com links.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Egorov for taking time to write for me!